# how to list a table/model view within another view by parent id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to MVC in addition to C#, so...  please work with me.

I'm developing a simple MVC project - Sales system, so I have 3 tables in SQL

`Prospects, Contacts, Activities`

I'm used to relating tables a little differently I guess because I am definitely stuck.

I have 3 controllers, 3 models, and 3 views for these three tables.  I have CRUD functionality set up, and things have been progressing reasonably well.

My issue is having one relate to another.  So for example, when I open the index view for prospects, I have a grid of all the prospects.  I then have an actionlink on each prospect name to take me to the edit view.

Within that, I have been able to list the edit fields for the specific prospect(easy), and then I have a grid of activities except that it's all activities, not just activities with the same prospected as the chosen prospect.  Where would I make this connection?  I understand there's the chance that I'm just not far enough along technical wise to get there, but I'd any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Even anything to get me closer.  Examples are my best friend.  Thanks everyone.

**View - Prospect/Edit**
- how I'm showing all activities
    `@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Activity");}`

**Activity Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Activities.ToList());
}
```

**Activity Model**

```
public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int ProspectId { get; set; }
    public int ProspectName{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What are you using for the Models? Entity framework or Plain Old Classes??

Comment: public class CRMSystemDb : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Prospect> Prospects {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        
    }